# Printing JSON Data into innerHTML getting undefined - [object]

Tags: javascript, html, json

Hi guys Im trying to print a list of scores saved within a database, ive got the data as JSON data (see below)
[image: JSON Data]

I am trying to print all each object within the "Scores" array using the following code

```
    function showScores() {
        var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var x, i = "";
        ourRequest.open('GET', '/allScores');
        ourRequest.onload = function() {
           var ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
           for (i in ourData.scores) {
               x += ourData.scores[i] + "<br>";
           }
           document.getElementById("scoresList").innerHTML = x;
        };
        ourRequest.send();
    }
```

However it is printing out the following

[image: Print out]

Any help with this is greatly appreciated, thanks guys

Comment: `x` should be initialized. Try with this version: `function showScores() {
  var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest(), x = "";
  ourRequest.open('GET', '/allScores');
  ourRequest.onload = function() {
    var ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
    for (var i in ourData.scores) {
      x += ourData.scores[i] + "<br>";
    }
    document.getElementById("scoresList").innerHTML = x;
  };
  ourRequest.send();
}`.

Comment: so you are trying to append the json to the html. Do you have any table structure or ul li ?

Comment: Hi Danny, initialising got rid of the undefined, however still getting [object, Object] twice, and Dileep Im using <div id="Scores">
    <ul id="scoresList">
    </ul>
</div>

Comment: To show JSON or JS Objects in html try embedded javascript (ejs) https://ejs.co/

Comment: `x += ourData.scores[i]` This is just appending a raw object to your HTML string. Javascript can’t magically parse this into HTML for you, so it just outputs `[object Object]`. You could access individual parts of this object and print those instead (eg: `x += ourData.scores[i].Away_score`)

Comment: `ourData.scores[i]` is the currenct object of the iteration. Just set the proper property of this object in your code. E.g: 
`function showScores() { var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest(), x = ""; ourRequest.open('GET', '/allScores'); ourRequest.onload = function() { var ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText); for (var i in ourData.scores) { x += ourData.scores[i].Home_Score + "<br>"; } document.getElementById("scoresList").innerHTML = x; }; ourRequest.send(); }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line tries to append a raw object to your HTML string:

```js
x += ourData.scores[i]
```

Javascript can’t magically parse this into HTML for you, so it just outputs `[object Object]`.

You need to build a string from the individual parts of this object and print that instead. For example:

*Note that you should not use `for ... in` with an array*

```js
ourData.scores.forEach(function (score) {
  x += `<p>[H] ${score.Home_Team} <b>${score.Home_Score}</b> - <b>${score.Away_Score}</b> ${score.Away_Team} [A]</p>`;
});
```

Which would output something like this for each score:

> [H] Arsenal **2** - **2** Newcastle [A]

**Be sure to set `x = ""` before the loop otherwise the string will still start with `undefined`.**

---

In case you’re interested: there are more succinct ways of writing this loop. Using [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for instance:

```js
let x = ourData.scores.map(score => {
  return `<p>[H] ${score.Home_Team} <b>${score.Home_Score}</b> - <b>${score.Away_Score}</b> ${score.Away_Team} [A]</p>`;
}).join();
```

This expression does not require initialization of `x` beforehand.

Comment: Still have to address `undefined + String`

Answer (score 0):

you can create the elements as string and you can join the entire array and assign it to the innerHTML, as shown below.

You can change the structure, here for example i had made to ul , li you can create table or whatever format.

**Note** if you want to just append it, since the object you can't directly append it using [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) which will convert your object into string.

I hope this will solve your issue. Please let me know if any other issue you are facing.

```js
var jsonObj = {scores: [{"Away_Score": 2, "Away_Team": "Newcastle", "Home_Score": 2, "Home_Team": "Arsenal"}, {"Away_Score": 2, "Away_Team": "Napoli", "Home_Score": 4, "Home_Team": "Liverpool"}]}

var html = jsonObj.scores.map(o => {
 return `<ul><li>${o.Away_Team}</li><li>${o.Away_Score}</li><li>${o.Home_Team}</li><li>${o.Home_Score}</li></ul>`
})

document.getElementById("todaysData").innerHTML = html.join("")
```

```html
<div id="todaysData">

</div>
```